# Proof Assistance: Pinter Chapter 10 Exercise G5

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

In Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra", the reader is asked to prove that the order of $a^m$ is equivalent to $\frac{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}{m}$ **using the following two facts** (which were proved in previous exercises):

1. $(a^m)^{{\rm lcm}(m,n)*\frac{1}{m}}$ = e
2. Given that $(a^m)^t=e$, ${\rm lcm}(m,n) \leq m*t$

Side note: the order for the element $a$ in this group is equal to $n$... ( ${\rm ord}(a)=n$).

My work so far has included the following steps:

By 1. , I know that ${\rm ord}(a^m) \leq \frac{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}{m}$.

By 2. , I know that $\frac{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}{m}\leq t$

This results in the following inequality:

${\rm ord}(a^m) \leq \frac{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}{m}\leq t$

And this is where I am stumped. I obviously need to somehow demonstrate that ${\rm ord}(a^m)$ cannot be less than $\frac{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}{m}$. However, if this is the case, I'm not  quite certain why I need the proof from 2. to help establish this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Order $a^m$ is $t$ by definition

Comment: How so? Couldn't t just be a multiple of the order of $a^m$

Comment: Oh, thank you! I looked on google and this did not show up (hence my question). I'll give it a look

Comment: If you're still stuck after that you can ask questions here or there.

Comment: No, Sir. That link was just the thing I was looking for! Cheers~